# Datas - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Ola! Não estou conseguindo comparar as datas de um input do usuário com a data de hoje. Para poder retornar um alerta ao usuário. 
Fiz um outro exemplo e funcionou, mas esse não foi. Alguém consegue enxergar o(s) erro(s)?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function validarData(){

    var data_entrega = document.getElementById('data_entrega').value;

    var data = new Date(); //obtem data hoje

    var dia     = data.getDate();           // 1-31
    var mes     = data.getMonth();          // 0-11 (zero=janeiro)
    var ano4    = data.getFullYear();       // 4 dígitos



    var data_hoje = dia + '/' + (mes+1) + '/' + ano4; //formatação igual ao input do usuário


    var sete_dias = data_hoje + 7; // regra 7 dias (chroma)



    if(data_entrega < data_hoje){

        alert("Atenção! Data de entrega já passou!");


    }else if(data_entrega > sete_dias){

        alert("Atenção! Data de entrega ultrapassa 7 dias!");


    }


}
    

</script>
```

```html
    <input type="date" name="data_entrega" id="data_entrega" class="form-control" value="" required="" onblur="validarData()">
```

Obrigada!

Comment: Obrigada por responder. Então, estou trazendo pelo evento Onblur no input, pego o valor dele ( var data_entrega = document.getElementById('data_entrega').value;). Tem que fazer algo mais?

Comment: Consegui resolver! Obrigada de qualquer forma! Tinha que formatar a data do usuário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O formato do `data_hoje` está errado em relação à data capturada no `input`.

É preciso tratar os valores do dia e do mês para terem 2 dígitos caso só tenham 1 (como mês de janeiro até setembro) e dias de 1 a 9, para terem o padrão `YYYY/MM/DD`.

Veja funcionando:

```js
function validarData(){

    var data_entrega = document.getElementById('data_entrega').value;
    
    var data_entrega_array = data_entrega.split( data_entrega.indexOf("/") != -1 ? "/" : "-" );
    
    if(data_entrega_array[2].length == 4){
       data_entrega = data_entrega_array[2]+"-"+data_entrega_array[1]+"-"+data_entrega_array[0];
    }

    var data = new Date(); //obtem data hoje

    var dia     = data.getDate();           // 1-31
    var mes     = data.getMonth()+1;          // 0-11 (zero=janeiro)
    var ano4    = data.getFullYear();       // 4 dígitos

    if(dia.toString().length == 1) dia = '0'+dia;
    if(mes.toString().length == 1) mes = '0'+mes;

    var data_hoje = ano4 + '-' + mes + '-' + dia; //formatação igual ao input do usuário


    var sete_dias = ano4 + '-' + mes + '-' + parseInt(dia+7); // regra 7 dias (chroma)

    if(data_entrega < data_hoje){

        alert("Atenção! Data de entrega já passou!");


    }else if(data_entrega > sete_dias){

        alert("Atenção! Data de entrega ultrapassa 7 dias!");


    }


}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="data_entrega" id="data_entrega" class="form-control" value="" required="" onblur="validarData()">
```